# Assigning value to property

Tags: c#-4.0

How do I pass in a class property to a method and have it assigned a value?

For example, below is a simple scenario.  The inner workings of the method will be a little more complex.

```
Action <string> MyMethod = (myString) =>
{
  myString = "testing...";
};
```

and then call it this way

```
MyMethod (someClass.String1);
MyMethod (someClass.String2);
MyMethod (someClass.String3);
```

Such that each of the three properties retain an assigned value from the method.  As it is, none of the properties will retain a value.  They will be null.

I don't want to pass the class in because that means the method will need logic to figure if it is assigning to String1, String2, or String3.  I'd like it to remain very generic.

Comment: Must your Action be of that specific definition?

Comment: I would like to keep this very concise, inline and not have to split this into several constructs.

Comment: I do not know of a way to declare delegates inside methods so I removed my answer...

Comment: I think you would have to iterate over the class properties? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151888/c-sharp-iterate-through-class-properties

Comment: This requires knowledge about each specific property and moves away from a more generic approach.