# Using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997747/accessing-the-fields-of-a-struct) answer, I'm trying to replicate it and iterate over my CustomerModel properties.

```
CustomerModel pippo = new CustomerModel();
Type customer = pippo.GetType();
FieldInfo[] fields = customer.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

When using the debugger, `fields` always has a `count = 0` but CustomerModel has a lot of public properties I'd like to see in fields. How can I do that? Here's an extract of some properties declared I'd like to see.

```
    [DataMember]
    public String Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String LoginName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Password { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String CreationDate { get; set; }
```

Perhaps the binding flags are incorrect? I'm new to the use of reflection.

Comment: I'd recommend changing the variable name from `customer` to `customerType` or something like that. `customer` sounds more like an instance of `CustomerModel`, rather than its type.

Comment: yeah, I won't even store the variable anymore but just get the properties... This was just for testing purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are properties, not fields. Use `GetProperties` instead of `GetFields`.

In C#:

```
public class Foo {

    // this is a field:
    private string _name;

    // this is a property:
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // this is also a property:
    public string SomethingElse { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }

}
```

Comment: It's working! Thanks a lot and forgive the stupid question but this is really the first time I use reflections... Thanks again! :)

Comment: No problem. As you get more and more into reflection, you'll find all kinds of cool stuff you can do with it (and a lot of dangerous stuff too :))

Answer (score 2):

As Joe correctly pointed out the members in question are properties not fields.  These are auto-implemented properties and the compiler will generate backing fields for them.  However these fields won't be public hence the `GetFields` call fails because it is looking for the public members only.  If you want to see the generated fields then change the code to the following

```
FieldInfo[] fields = customer.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: +1 I'm not interested right now into retrieving private fields, but this is something new I've just learned - thanks for posting!